# run curl from windows task scheduler automatically

Tags: windows, schedule

I have a simple one line bat file that runs a curl localhost:port. My curl.exe is in the same folder as the bat I don't have it installed globally. It runs fine if I double click it, it also runs fine if I right click in task scheduler and select run task. It also says it completes the "scheduled tasks" successfully but nothing happens (I'm sure of this as I'm checking data that should update if the script is run, and it doesn't happen under the scheduled/automatic scenarios). After reading lots of users issues I tried configuring in two ways (all on 5 minute updates):

Common Way

`Action: Start a Program
Program/script: C:\p\updater.bat
Start in: C:\p\`

Other Way

`Action: Start a Program
Program/script: cmd
Add arguments: /c start "" "C:\p\updater.bat"`

I have set permissions to the bat and the containing folder to allow all for all users/etc. Neither work when automatically triggered, neither error. I've tried in Server 2008 and Windows 10 (my OS) mode. Both work if I right click run task, neither automatically, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default working directory for scheduled script is %Windows%\system32. Try to add in first line to you updater.bat:

```
cd c:\p\
```

For diagnostic, you can add output redirect to you commands in bat file:

```
echo Script Started >> c:\p\log.txt
curl SomeCommand SomeCommand >>c:\p:\curloutput.txt
echo Script Ended >> c:\p\log.txt
```

and check files log.txt and curloutput.txt after execution of your script

Comment: Thanks for this helpful response. My script now includes the cd and echos. If I run the script manually it works and logs Started Ended. The scheduler doesn't seem to hit to start the script. Oddly, it now updates the next run time but the last run is not updating, the script is enabled and "ready". I just tried adding another repeating trigger to see if that helps. Should I run in win 10 or Server 2008 mode if I'm on windows 10?

Comment: If you will not see "Script Started" in c:\p\log.txt, it means: 1) Scheduler can't start script. 2) Script don't have necessary permission to write into your directory

Comment: try to execute task from your user. Open task properties. Find:
"Then use this task, use the following user account". Press "Change User or Group", find your account. In my case it Michael.Press Ok. Your account name will have text like "YouComputerName/YourAccountName". You must use "Run whether user is logged on or not". !!!Uncheck!!! "Do not store password". Press Ok. You will be asked about your password. Enter it.

Comment: All these are helpful comments all ++ed. The original answer was correct for my issue, including CD in the bat fixed it not executing correctly. The issue I had thereafter I resolved by creating another trigger and deleting the original, I don't know why disable/enable did not work, but it is working for me and I will call this solved.

Comment: As @edencorbin wrote, same works for me. Reenabling the job didnt work, I must create the new job and then it works.